# Add custom field only to error logs in logrus

Tags: go, logrus

I'm using `logrus` for logging in golang. I use the following statements for logging.

```
logger.Info("")
logger.Errorf("Error message")
```

My requirement is to have a custom field (severity) only in `Errorf` statements with the following constraints.

1. If it is specified in the log statement (Ex: `logrus.WithField("severity", "critical").Errorf("Error message")`) it should print the specified value as below.

```
ERRO[0000] Error message            severity=critical
```

2. If it is not specified, it should print a default value. For Example this(`logger.Errorf("Error message")`) log statement should print the follows.

```
ERRO[0000] Error message            severity=normal
```

Note : This should happen only for `Errorf` statements, which means others should works as normal.

Can someone suggest me a way to achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write custom `Hook` that will check if entry has `severity` field set and if not insert default value. Attach that hook to either default global or your own logger.

You can limit hook to fire only on entries on `logrus.ErrorLevel` by including only that level in return value of `Hook.Levels()`:

```golang
type ErrorHook struct {
}

func (h *ErrorHook) Levels() []logrus.Level {
    // fire only on ErrorLevel (.Error(), .Errorf(), etc.)
    return []logrus.Level{logrus.ErrorLevel}
}

func (h *ErrorHook) Fire(e *logrus.Entry) error {
    // e.Data is a map with all fields attached to entry
    if _, ok := e.Data["severity"]; !ok {
        e.Data["severity"] = "normal"
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    logrus.AddHook(&ErrorHook{})

    logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"animal": "walrus"}).Info("A walrus appears")
    // time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="A walrus appears" animal=walrus
    logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"animal": "walrus"}).Error("A error walrus appears")
    // time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=error msg="A error walrus appears" animal=walrus severity=normal
    logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{"animal": "walrus", "severity": "high"}).Error("An overriden severity error walrus appears")
    // time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=error msg="An overriden severity error walrus appears" animal=walrus severity=high
}
```